# unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇô'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding, mpeg

I'm trying to encode videos for mpeg dash streaming, I used the following command (I bring it from this article: http://blog.streamroot.io/encode-multi-bitrate-videos-mpeg-dash-mse-based-media-players/) :

```
cd c:\ffmpeg\bin
set inputFile="C:\park.mp4"
set outputFile="C:\content\park"

ffmpeg -y -i %inputFile% -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -c:v libx264 -r 24 – g 24 -b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 1000k -vf "scale=-1:720" %outputFile%_720.mp4
```

after run the command the following issue appear:

```
[NULL @ 0000000002f43dc0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇô' ΓÇô: Invalid argument
```

I tried other videos but the error is the same.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Judging from the way the title looks on my machine, it appears there may be a character encoding issue with the command you're trying to issue. I'm using the latest version of Firefox, but after the word "for" in your title looks like gibberish. Maybe ffmpeg is having trouble with that as well.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have a "special" hyphen followed by a space before the "g" in the middle of your command line, it is known as an "[en dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)" and it is confusing your parser.

To compare:

```
Hyphen:  -
Em dash: —
En dash: –
```

Your script should be (to the best of my knowledge):

```
cd c:\ffmpeg\bin
set inputFile="C:\park.mp4"
set outputFile="C:\content\park"

ffmpeg -y -i %inputFile% -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -c:v libx264 -r 24 -g 24 -b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 1000k -vf "scale=-1:720" %outputFile%_720.mp4
```

I would assume that the article you copied the script from was created using some kind of word processor which automatically substituted the em-dash  after a space was accidentally typed before the "g" and from there it got copied and pasted into the rest of the article.

Hint garnered from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000392/how-to-parse-word-created-special-chars-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see:  you have a space between the dash and the `g` for specifying gop length.  I think FFmpeg believes you are trying to save an output with the name "-".  Try deleting the space.